# System ignore iPhone rotation

Tags: iphone, events, rotation, ios4, uiapplication

Is there a function like beginIgnoringInteractionEvents in UIApplication that ignores rotation instead of touches? I need my app NOT to rotate just in an `MPMovePlayerViewController` that I present.

Thanks

[UPDATE]

Here's my code --

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *mpViewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:videoURL]];
[mpViewController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight animated:NO];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mpViewController];
[mpViewController release];
```

I got it working by adding both the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: and setStatusBarOrientation: methods. It works in the simulator. However if I rotate the iPhone while the video is playing, the status bar rotates as well and stays 'stuck' in the portrait orientation.

image of my problem at http://i28.tinypic.com/357mrub.png

[UPDATE 2]

By subclassing MPMoviePlayerViewController (and implementing the shouldAutorotate method), the program rotates as it should. Only the video doesn't play because the line

```
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mpViewController];
```

doesn't accept my subclass.

"warning: incompatible Objective-C types 'struct NoRotate *', expected 'struct MPMoviePlayerViewController *' when passing argument 1 of 'presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:' from distinct Objective-C type"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the view you present, implement the shouldAutoRotate method and simply return "NO".  This will cause the phone to ignore any and all orientation changes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could subclass the MPMoviePlayerViewController like this

```
// NotRotatingMoviePlayerViewController.h
@interface NotRotatingMoviePlayerViewController : MPMoviePlayerViewController {
}

@end

// NotRotatingMoviePlayerViewController.m
@implementation

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
  return (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks, it works only the video won't play.

    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mpViewController];

this is the warning it gives me 
"warning: incompatible Objective-C types 'struct NoRotate *', expected 'struct MPMoviePlayerViewController *' when passing argument 1 of 'presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:' from distinct Objective-C type"