# How do I lock the screen orientation to landscape during a scene in cocos2d?

Tags: ios4, ios5, cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

I am using box2d for ios app development.I would like to fix device orientation to landscape left which comes default in cocos2d.

How would I go about locking the screen orientation so that it cannot be changed while the user is playing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer to your question:

[System ignore iPhone rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229809/system-ignore-iphone-rotation)

You tell the OS to ignore system rotations.

Answer (score 0):

In Cocos2D open the GameConfig.h and change the Autorotation macro according to its documentation to disable autorotate support.